# Ubuntu focal 2 networks , two default gateways ==> no connectivity

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, router

I am using Ubuntu Focal 20

```
uname -a
Linux domaintf 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with 2 netowrk interfaces

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:f3:a6:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.10.226/24 brd 10.20.10.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 85607sec preferred_lft 85607sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fef3:a6ef/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:63:bc:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.20.169/24 brd 10.20.20.255 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 85607sec preferred_lft 85607sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe63:bcb5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

the default netplan contents are the following

```
cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:f3:a6:ef
            mtu: 1450
            set-name: ens3
        ens4:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:63:bc:b5
            mtu: 1450
            set-name: ens4
```

By Default I got two default route with the same metric which is blocking me from connecting to addresses that can be advertised by both

```
ip r
**default via 10.20.20.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.20.20.169 metric 100
default via 10.20.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.20.10.226 metric 100**
10.20.10.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.10.226
10.20.20.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.20.169
169.254.169.254 via 10.20.20.2 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.20.20.169 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.20.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.20.10.226 metric 100
```

The WA is as simple as modifying the netplan metric

s

```
udo cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
sudo netpl# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            **dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 100**
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:f3:a6:ef
            mtu: 1450
            set-name: ens3
        ens4:
            dhcp4: true
            **dhcp4-overrides:**
                **route-metric: 300**
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:63:bc:b5
            mtu: 1450
            set-name: ens4
ip r
default via 10.20.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.20.10.226 metric 100
**default via 10.20.20.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.20.20.169 metric 300**
10.20.10.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.10.226
10.20.20.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.20.169
169.254.169.254 via 10.20.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.20.10.226 metric 100
**169.254.169.254 via 10.20.20.2 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.20.20.169 metric 300**
```

Ultimately the bug should be fixed by not allowing two default gateways with the same metrics by default ; **then as a temporary workaround I would like to ask your help to guide me how can I configure it via cloud init**

I have tried the following config , but it didn't work

```
cat cloudinit2.txt
#cloud-config
password: password
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
write_files:
  - path: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
    permissions: '0644'
    content: |
        network:
            version: 2
            ethernets:
                ens3:
                    dhcp4: true
                    dhcp4-overrides:
                        route-metric: 100
                     mtu: 1450
                     set-name: ens3
                ens4:
                    dhcp4: true
                    dhcp4-overrides:
                        route-metric: 200
                     mtu: 1450
                     set-name: ens4
runcmd:
 - sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Hey Mohamed, I looks like your indentation is off by 1 space in the `cloudinit2.txt` file for the `mtu` and `set-name` settings of both interfaces. Also, you could consider naming your netplan configuration file `/etc/netplan/90-custom-config.yaml` instead of 50-cloud-init.yaml, to avoid conflicts with files generated by cloud-init.

What exactly is the problem you see with this cloud-init configuration? Can you elaborate what didn't work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Lukas , I follow your advices and I got the configuration passed

```
 cat netcloud
#cloud-config
password: password
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
write_files:
  - path: /etc/netplan/90-custom-config.yaml
    permissions: '0644'
    content: |
        network:
            version: 2
            ethernets:
                ens3:
                    dhcp4: true
                    dhcp4-overrides:
                        route-metric: 100
                    mtu: 1450
                    set-name: ens3
                ens4:
                    dhcp4: true
                    dhcp4-overrides:
                        route-metric: 200
                    mtu: 1450
                    set-name: ens4
runcmd:
 - sudo netplan apply
```